# Python - min() max() of list with NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Can anyone tell me why looking for the minimum value in a list using min(list) is not working when NaN is the first element of the list? The same applies when using max(list)

```
import math

y = [float('nan'),1,2,3,0,float('nan'),6,7,8,9]
print(y)
print(math.isnan(y[0]))
print(min(y))


w = [10,1,2,3,0,float('nan'),6,7,8,9]
print(w)
print(min(w))
print(math.isnan(w[5]))
```

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any comparison operation performed on **nan** with a number will return *False*.

```
print(y[1] > y[0])
print(y[1] < y[0])
```

Results in

```
False
False
```

If the built-in function follows the same logic while comparing the elements the above behavior is easily explained. If the first element is selected as min element any comparison afterward will be False hence returning **nan** as min element.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter `y` or `w` to ignore `nan`:

```
print(min(i for i in y if not math.isnan(i)))
# 0
```

Comment: while this is true, I don't think it answer's OP's question regarding _why_ it doesn't work, which has to do with how python compares elements to NaN